# It is possible to parallize JSON.parse in Node

Tags: node.js

It is possible to parallelize the next line?. That line process is a huge file which has several JSON events. The variable that contains that huge string is payload.

```
 const logevents = JSON.parse(zlib.unzipSync(payload).toString()).logEvents;
```

Actually, this line is taken about 1m. Coud you help me to paralleize this line, please?

Comment: If you just need the one property, you can scan the output of `zlib.unzipSync()` for a top-level property `"logEvents"` and call `JSON.parse()` only on the extracted value rather than the entire object. Of course this only makes a difference if there's lots of data that you want to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't parallelize JSON.parse
2. `zlib.unzipSync(payload).toString()` will copy a lot of memory to generate a string, you can consider using a stream-oriented library to process it(e.g. https://github.com/uhop/stream-json)